# Simple question regarding Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I have been reading about conditional independence given a graph but I still don't understand. Given the graph below, B is said to be conditionally independent of C given A. But even if A is not given, then $ P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) $ right ? It still does not depend on C...[image]

Comment: http://lesswrong.com/lw/2b0/bayes_theorem_illustrated_my_way/ best conditional probability intuitive guide I've seen, just my two cents. it's hard to tell exaxtly what the diagram is trying to say maybe mutually exlusice?

Comment: Two events $B$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $A$ if $P(B \bigcap C \mid A) = P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A)$

Comment: My question was what if A is not given

Comment: $P(B \mid A)$ is the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$ . It is defined as $P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(B \bigcap A)}{P(A)}$. Rearranging the formula we get $P(B \bigcap A) = P(B \mid A)\;P(A)$. Your formula is not correct. Conditional independence and conditional probabilities are related but different concepts.

Comment: Hi thanks. I think I am getting confused because the sentence is "B is independent of C given A" which leads me to wonder what if A is not given ? Then is B dependent on C ?

Comment: To see why $B$ and $C$ are not independent in general, look at the extreme case such that the dependencies $A\to B$ and $A\to C$ are that $A=B=C$, then $P(B\cap C)=P(A)$ while $P(B)P(C)=P(A)^2$ hence $P(B\cap C)\ne P(B)P(C)$ except if $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$. Now that you get the idea, consider the less degenerate case where $P(B\mid A)=P(C\mid A)=P(\bar B\mid\bar A)=p$ and $P(\bar C\mid\bar A)=q$ for some given $p$ and $q$, and $P(A)=\frac12$. Then you should be able to write down explicitely $P(B\cap C)$ and $P(B)=P(C)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ and to check that $P(B\cap C)\ne P(B)P(C)$, ...

Comment: ... except maybe for some specific values of $p$ and $q$. In particular, by the extreme case above, values of $p$ close $1$ should work. If you cannot complete this program, post a comment.

Comment: Wow thanks so much ! That explanation was simple and it has cleared my doubt !